# Using regular expressions in Java to do a partial search

Tags: java, regex, variables, search, partial

ETA at 9:42 p.m. March 21: Dumb mistake. I made sure the original creation of the object made the name .toUpperCase(). The partial search didn't find the search term because they weren't capitalized. Edited code below. Thank you all for the help.

---

I'm trying to figure out how to use regular expressions to find out if any pattern of characters matches what's in the object.

For instance, if the name associated with the object was "StackOverflow," I'd like for someone to search "ck" and make the if statement true. So, why is my if statement here not returning true?

ETA: i.getName() returns a string. The program is looping through an ArrayList of objects to find which object has a name that matches the input.

```
    System.out.println("What name or partial name would you like to filter?");
    String name = input.nextLine();
    int count = 0;
    for (MyObject i: testObject) {
        if (i.getName().matches(".*" + name.toUpperCase() + ".*")) {
            count++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why use `matches` instead of [`contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence))?

Comment: Is there a reason you're iterating over `Object`s? Seems like you should be comparing `String`s.

Comment: @matt sorry, didn't want to post too much code. The program is sifting through an ArrayList of objects, with getName() getting the String name of the object.

Comment: I don't think `Object` has a `getName` method? Your code works if you compare `String`s so I think there's something else going on.

Comment: @matt I'm not doing this very well. I have a separate class (not named object but it's creating objects). Poorly named in this question. Changed to MyObject to avoid confusion? So I'm iterating through these objects in a for:each loop. Each of these objects has a method I defined as getName() that returns a string.

Comment: Ohh I see, that makes more sense. It's good to avoid using names that are taken, especially `Object` as it's the class that everything else inherits from.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use toString(). You can not apply matches over an object.

Try that:

```
System.out.println("What name or partial name would you like to filter?");
String name = input.nextLine();
int count = 0;
for (Object i: testObject) {
    if (i.getName().toString().matches(".*" + name + ".*")) {
        count++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your code doesn't work, but see this working example, perhaps you have a small mistake somewhere.

Here's a `MyObject` class that has a `name` field:

```
class MyObject {
    private final String name;

    public MyObject(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

and here's the program that find matches:

```
List<MyObject> myObjects = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
myObjects.add(new MyObject("Stack Overflow"));
myObjects.add(new MyObject("Stack Exchange"));

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("What name or partial name would you like to filter? ");
String pattern = input.nextLine();

int count = 0;
for (MyObject i: myObjects) {
    if (i.getName().matches(".*" + pattern + ".*")) {
        count++;
    }
}

System.out.println("Matches: " + count);
```

Input:

```
ck
```

Output:

```
Matches: 2
```